# Pgbouncer log shows only 0 req/s

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

It's my first stackoverflow post so I wanted so say hi! ;)

I have question regarding pgbouncer. I just started using that together with my django app and postgres.
I though everything is set up correctly, but I get only such information in log:

```
"LOG Stats: 0 req/s, in 0 b/s, out 0 b/s"
```

It seems like it is not running, or do I miss its concept? There are no other errors, except of those stat lines with just 0s. The app is constantly running with tens of people using it every second, making database connections, so there should be something logged right?
Do you have any clue why this could happen? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe clients have their connection string still target postgres server instead of PgBouncer?

Comment: Might be, how can I check and change that? Sorry, this might sound like a stupid question, but I am not an database expert! Thanks!

Comment: connect to pgbouncer db and run `show clients`

Comment: or easier, psql to postgres and `select client_addr from pg_stat_activity` to check if connections are coming from pgbounce host

Comment: Easiest way to deploy PgBouncer would be to change postgres listen port to non-default and set PgBouncer to default postgres port. This way you don't have to change anything in client software.

Comment: Thx guys that was very helpful! I managed to make it work! Amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgbouncer listens on e.g. port 6543 and your postgres db on port 5543. Your application has to connect to pgbouncer not to the postgres database.

your_app -> pgbouncer -> postgres

Just edit the app config and add the port of pgbouncer, here 6543. Of course your `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini` should contain the postgres database port 5543.

You can find a useful documentation here:
[pgbouncer docu](https://pgbouncer.github.io/usage.html)